# Under which prefix shimmercat should be installed?

Tags: shimmercat

I was trying to install Shimmercat and got stuck on a point that in which prefix to install ShimmerCat?

Should I install it in :- (/usr/local)?

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation is that you use `/usr/local` as the prefix. You can also choose another directory, but then you have to be sure to have enough privileges there, and that there is a "bin" subdirectory in your PATH. You shouldn't need to use root privileges for running the installer